# JavaFX - How to remove ListView & TableView's bands?

Tags: java, css, listview, javafx, tableview

I'm adding JavaFX ListViews & TableViews to my app in their default style.

The odd rows got a white background and even rows got a grey background.
I don't like those bands, especially on unpopulated rows.

I tried the following CSS settings on my ListView with fxid:list_PayMethod but doesn't help.

(this page doesn't recognize the fxid as part of the code, so it is not inside the grey box, please note.)

```css
#list_PayMethod {

    .list-cell:odd {
        -fx-padding: 0px;
        -fx-control-background: #F4F4F4;
        -fx-control-inner-background: #F4F4F4;
    }

    .list-cell:even {
        -fx-padding: 0px;
        -fx-control-background: #F4F4F4;
        -fx-control-inner-background: #F4F4F4;
    }

    .list-view:focused .list-cell:focused:odd {
        -fx-padding: 0px;
        -fx-control-background: #F4F4F4;
        -fx-control-inner-background: #F4F4F4;
    }

    .list-view:focused .list-cell:focused:even {
        -fx-padding: 0px;
        -fx-control-background: #F4F4F4;
        -fx-control-inner-background: #F4F4F4;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set all to write or all grey?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `-fx-control-background` with `-fx-background-color` and that should be enough.

```css
.list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you are using the correct id. What is `list_PayMethod`? is it your controller or just the `ListView`?

Comment: Did you change anything else?

Comment: I removed the #list_PayMethod {} and then it works, but this created another problem because I don't want the combo boxes to be affected. if the fxid of the ListView I want to config is list_PayMethod, what should be the code?

Comment: You should use a style class. `list.getStyleClass().add("one-color-list");` and then in you css file: 
`.one-color-list .list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: #F4F4F4;
}`

Comment: One more question to ask... Previously when the row is selected, the background will become blue and the text become white. But now because the background is always grey. The white text become difficult to read. I try adding "-fx-text-fill: black;" but the font color remain white when selected

Comment: You have to set this: `.list-cell:filled:selected`

Comment: In fact my listView is for containing listCell objects. I tried your suggestion, but it failed....I think I have to spend some time on css. Well, I found a way to workaround and changed all the Label controls to Text controls. Because Label text color will change when selection state changes but Text will not. My app is now working perfectly. Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: I added a combobox in the listCell today for some reason and found that editing the listview properties have profound effect on its content....The style of the combobox is severely affected and it looks awful.... Is there any way to just set the background of the listview but leave combobox in the listCell alone?

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, you should give a style class to the list you want to style and use that style in css: `.one-color-list .list-cell { -fx-background-color: #F4F4F4; }`. This way, your ComboBox will not get affected.

Comment: I already did it.....The comboBoxes outside the listView are not affected. But the comboBoxes inside the listCells are affected. Because the listCells are inside the listView

Comment: I captured some images to illustrate the situation [link](https://ibb.co/thwLmQQ)
[link](https://ibb.co/HP080hz)
[link](https://ibb.co/n01DQ9N)

Comment: I see.. if this is your case, use id instead of class style: `#someList { -fx-background-color: #F4F4F4; }`.

Comment: The ComboBoxes inside the ListCells will still be affected because the ListCells are inside the ListView. I'm thinking about adding another style to the Combobox to override the setting I made on the ListView. But I can't find the default settings of a normal ComboBox

Comment: Yes, actually you can assign a class for those `ComboBox`s and don't forget to use the keyword `!important` to make the `ComboBox`'s color overrides the color coming from the `ListView`

Comment: The default for modena style is `-fx-background-color: transparent;`

Comment: Do you know the default settings for a combobox? I tried some different settings but it only make it more weird and affected the datepicker as well

Comment: Check modena.css and try to find out what is missing in your class file.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I look up the modena.css and look for anything that applies to combo & list-cells, override them one by one and identified the cause. It is now fully fixed.

Comment: @katana glad to hear that